# Attempt to Index nil with Name

Tags: lua, roblox

Im creating a script using remote functions, but at `elseif part2.Name==selected.Name` is says: "attempt to index nil with Name" here is the script:

```
 game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.PlaceBlock.OnServerInvoke= function(player,pos,selected)
        for i,part2 in ipairs(parts:GetChildren()) do
            if part2== nil then
                partPlace= parts.BasicPart
            elseif part2.Name==selected.Name then
                partPlace = selected:Clone()
            end
        end
        partPlace.CFrame = CFrame.new(math.ceil(pos.X), math.ceil(pos.Y)+2, math.ceil(pos.Z))
        partPlace.Orientation = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
        partPlace.Parent = player.Plate.Value.Parts
        partPlace.Owner.Value=player
    end
```

Comment: Seeing as you do a `nil` check of `part2`, your problem is that `selected` = `nil`

Comment: Seth OwO, could you share the code where you call `PlaceBlock:InvokeServer(pos, selected)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably, that selected is nil (maybe you forgot to pass a third argument when you called the function, or it was nil).